# Distinguish between adwords, organic visits, facebook organic and facebook ads in my admin system

Tags: php, facebook, google-analytics, google-ads-api, facebook-ads-api

I'm trying to track leads from adwords, google organic visits, facebook organic and facebook ads in my admin system for reporting purposes.

Adwords shows me the conversions/leads and analytics shows me the google organic goals/leads, but I'm also capturing all leads into a web admin system automatically when an enquiry form is filled in by a website user. In the admin system, staff can change the status of a lead/client to "invoiced" once that lead as resulted in an invoice.

So while I can see I had for example 100 adword leads and 25 organic leads and 10 invoices in the admin system, I can't tell the adwords/organic split of those invoices. I also want to track leads/invoices originating from Facebook organic and Facebook Ads.

My initial thought is that when adwords brings a client to the website, there needs to be some sort of referral string/url attached to website url at all times, so when the user completes the enquiry form, I can capture that string/url and indicate in the admin system that that enquiry originated from adwords.

For organic leads via google, if there is no referral string/url attached then that would mean it's organic.

For Facebook organic that resulted in a lead, surely I should also be able to add some sort of referral string/url attached to the website url and a different referral string/url for facebook ads that resulted in a lead?

What's the most practical way to go about this, if at all possible?

Thanks
Johno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store a unique id per visit/visitor both in your admin system and as [custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en) in Analytics (the id must not identify a user as a person, that would violate the TOS. Easiest way would be to use the client id from the GA cookie). Use the [Analytics reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) to pull channel information per visit/visitor into your system. This will introduce a delay (GA needs up to 24 hours to process information) but it will mean that channel information is consistent between Analytics and your system.